# Ceiling fan w/remote to two switches with fan and light

Tags: lighting

[image]
I wired my ceiling fan with remote like the picture.  Currently 1 wall with 2 switches turns the fan and light on, 2 other wall switches just turn the light on. The remote only controls the fan.  Is there a way to also wire it so I can control the light with the remote? They’re obviously two unused capped wires on the receiver.

Comment: does the remote break-out different fan speeds? If so, then it probably won't work on the fan's light.

Comment: Where did this image come from? It looks like it may be a screenshot, but the text is cut off and it's distracting from your question. Can you crop it to just the relevant part?

Comment: What make and model is your fan, and do you want the light to be dimmable at all from the remote or just on/off?